# Python json.loads() function already read last value,, why it throws error "expecting value",s,err.value?

Tags: python

I am new to json, I am  using python 3.4, to convert json to csv.

```
fp=open(json_path,'r')
for line in fp:
  raw_data=json.loads(line)
    for item in raw_data:
    code to process items
  print('header is:',header)
```

I can see the code has already read all the data in json_path, and the header is also printed out, but why it keeps go back to try to read another line, and then throws out an error, (`"Execting value",s, err.value`).

How should I change my code to load json file?

Comment: Do you have an empty line in the file? Add the data to the question

Comment: paste your json to take a look, but you cant try with `if line:`, or avoid the problem using `try: <do something> except: pass`, not recommended but may work

Comment: I would like to paste my  json file here, but the file is long. the structure of json file is:

Comment: I would like to paste my  json file here, but the file is long. the structure of json file is:{ "A": "a", "B":"b", "C":[{"C.11":"c11", "C.12":"c12"}, {"C.21":"c21", "C.22":"c22"}],  "D":"d", "E":[{"E.11":"e11", "E.12":"e12"}, {"E.21":"e21", "E.22":"e22"}]. There is no empty line in the end of the file.

Comment: Uhhh, that's not valid JSON -- for one thing, it starts with "{" and ends with "]"